# RESTful Web service in Java desktop application

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest

I'm currently working on a Java desktop application project. It's an existing application and I was asked to modify it.

They say that I have to send data from the desktop application to a web application using RESTful web service. So I search a bit about RESTful web service (cause I'm new with that kind of stuff and I'm also new with Java), and I saw some non-web applications that used RESTful web service but the non-web applications are Maven project. And the existing java desktop app that I need to modify is not a maven project.

So I was wondering if it's possible to use RESTful web service in java desktop app that is not a maven project?

Sorry for this question but I hope someone can help me. Please. Newbie here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hope your desktop application would act like a client (consume webserice)? if so this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommed you to use the [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) library. I have only good experiences with it and I used it a lot in servlet projects. If you do not use Maven, then simply download the `.jar` file [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) and copy it into your project. You also have to add it to your classpath.

If you want to know, how to implement simple REST clients with it, there is plenty of material out there, like [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html).